# Does Apache Drill support more than one character as delimiter?

Tags: apache-drill

I have a file which has double pipe as delimiter instead of comma or single pipe.

```
07||1||60||51111288||470||12647767||-1||0||-1||6||||77039144||-1||||||||||||||||||||||61807||||-1||1899-12-30 00:00:00.000||0||39||2019-03-07 17:15:56.000||1899-12-30 00:00:00.000||2019-03-07 17:23:35.000||0||0||0||-1578673||107||-1||-1||1||1||-1||-1||3||.000000||.000000||.000000||-1||.000000||-1||.000000||-1||.000000||.000000||2019-03-07 17:23:35.000||-1||-1||-1||-1||-1||-1||||||||-1||||||-1||||||1978955,2
```

Wanted to know how to configure storage in Apache Drill so that it can handle double pipe.

```
"formats": {
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv",
        "CSV"
      ],
      "delimiter": "||"
    }
```

If i give double pipe it throws error: `Please retry: error (invalid JSON mapping)`

As per this article https://drill.apache.org/blog/2015/12/14/drill-1.4-released/ a `linedelimiter` can have double character but nothing is mentioned for `delimiter`

Answer (score 1):

Currently java `byte` type is used for [delimiter setting](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/easy/text/compliant/TextParsingSettings.java#L33). That's why it is not possible to store several characters there, you will get Jackson serialization error (enable debug level log to find out this from logs).

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `char` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 25, column: 20] (through reference chain: org.apache.drill.exec.store.dfs.FileSystemConfig["formats"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["psv"]->org.apache.drill.exec.store.easy.text.TextFormatPlugin$TextFormatConfig["delimiter"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1138) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
...
```

Possibly it can be documented better. But as for me, it should be improved, so feel free to create a Jira ticket for this issue.